# почему не выводит минимумы из максимумов?

Tags: java, массивы

Создать программу, которая вводит c клавиатуры двумерный массив неотрицательных целых чисел, находит минимум из максимальных элементов каждой строки и выводит на экран этот минимум, все максимальные элементы строк, их местоположение в первоначальном массиве и число попыток ввести отрицательный элемент.
package com.example.mas;

```
 import java.util.Arrays;

 public class arr7 {
     public static void main(String[] args) {


    int[][] a = {{4, 3, 2, 1},
        {6, 7, 8, 9},
        {11, 12, 10, 13},
        {14, 16, 15, 17}};
    int [] b = new int [a[0].length];

   for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
   {
   int min = 0;
   int max = a[i][0];

       for (int element : a[i])
       {
           if (element > max)
           {
               max = element;
           }
          // min = max;
           if (max < min)
           {
               min = max;
           }
       }
   System.out.println(min);
   }

}
}
```

Comment: `if (max < min)` - никогда не будет, так как все элементы матрицы больше нуля

Answer (score 0):

Очень удобно при поиске min max в пределах Integer использовать константы Integer.MIN_VALUE и Integer.MAX_VALUE

Выделите 2 отдельные задачи :

- поиск максимального числа в массиве
- поиск минимального  среди 2 чисел.

Используя первый метод получите максимальное значение из каждого массива. Далее используя второй метод, найдете минимальное из этих максимумов.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int max = a[i][0];

    for (int element : a[i]) {
        if (element > max)
        {
            max = element;
        }
    }
    if (max < min) {
        min = max;
    }
    System.out.println(min);
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin А что в коде выше надо пояснять? Что такое минимум или максимум? Если Вам осталось что-то непонятным, напишите что.